# Why does this code behave differently with optomisations on or off?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a simple test runner for the bug which is in my OpenPGP module https://github.com/singpolyma/OpenPGP-Haskell/blob/master/Data/OpenPGP.hs:

```
module Main where

import Data.OpenPGP
import Data.Binary (encode, decode)

packet = EmbeddedSignaturePacket (signaturePacket 2 168 ECDSA SHA256 [] [SignatureCreationTimePacket 1013401916,IssuerPacket "36FE856F4219F1C7"] 48065 [MPI 4,MPI 11,MPI 60,MPI 69,MPI 37,MPI 33,MPI 18,MPI 72,MPI 41,MPI 36,MPI 43,MPI 41,MPI 53,MPI 9,MPI 53,MPI 35,MPI 3,MPI 40,MPI 14,MPI 79,MPI 1,MPI 4,MPI 51,MPI 23,MPI 62,MPI 62,MPI 62,MPI 7,MPI 68,MPI 51,MPI 13,MPI 49,MPI 8,MPI 64,MPI 32,MPI 50,MPI 59,MPI 17,MPI 43,MPI 12,MPI 67,MPI 5,MPI 67,MPI 5,MPI 25,MPI 63,MPI 0,MPI 53,MPI 2,MPI 36,MPI 83,MPI 39,MPI 54,MPI 65,MPI 54,MPI 35,MPI 62,MPI 63,MPI 26,MPI 4,MPI 82,MPI 57,MPI 85,MPI 71,MPI 43,MPI 77])

main = print $ decode (encode packet) == packet
```

If you compile this (on ghc 7.4.1) with:

```
ghc -O0 -fforce-recomp --make t.hs
```

It works as expected (that is, it prints `True`), but if you compile like this:

```
ghc -O1 -fforce-recomp --make t.hs
```

or this:

```
ghc -O2 -fforce-recomp --make t.hs
```

It will print `False`.

I'm not using any extensions (except a trivial use of CPP) or low-level or unsafe calls, and the behaviour should be from my library and not a dependency, since it's only my code that is getting recompiled here.

Comment: I can reproduce this bug in GHC 7.4.2

Comment: Are you using binary or cereal when you observe this bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an error in your code. Consider

```
MPI 63,MPI 0,MPI 53
       ^^^^^
```

and

```
instance BINARY_CLASS MPI where
    put (MPI i) = do
        put (((fromIntegral . B.length $ bytes) - 1) * 8
                + floor (logBase (2::Double) $ fromIntegral (bytes `B.index` 0))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                + 1 :: Word16)
    putSomeByteString bytes
    where
    bytes = if B.null bytes' then B.singleton 0 else bytes'
    bytes' = B.reverse $ B.unfoldr (\x ->
                    if x == 0 then Nothing else
                           Just (fromIntegral x, x `shiftR` 8)
             ) (assertProp (>=0) i)
```

Now, if we encode `MPI 0`, `bytes'` is empty, thus `bytes = B.singleton 0` and hence `` bytes `B.index` 0 `` is 0.

But `logBase 2 0` is `-Infinity`, and `floor` is only well-defined for finite values (within the range of the target type).

When compiling without optimisations, `floor` uses the bit-pattern via `decodeFloat`. Then `floor (logBase 2 0)` yields 0 for all standard fixed-width integer types.

With optimisations, a rewrite-rule is active and `floor` uses the primop `double2Int#`, which returns whatever the hardware does, on x86 resp. x86-64, that's `minBound :: Int`, as far as I know, regardless of the bit-pattern. The relevant code is

```
floorDoubleInt :: Double -> Int
floorDoubleInt (D# x) =
    case double2Int# x of
      n | x <## int2Double# n   -> I# (n -# 1#)
        | otherwise             -> I# n
```

and of course, `-Infinity < int2Double minBound`, so the value becomes `minBound - 1`, which usually is `maxBound`.

Of course that causes a wrong result, since now the "length" that is `put` for `MPI 0` becomes 0, and the 0 byte put after the "length" field is interpreted as part of the "length" of the next `MPI`.

Comment: Thanks!  I would not have expected the behaviour of `floor` to change with `-O`, but you're right that I had a bug in my assumptions anyway.

Comment: There are a few places where rewrite rules change the behaviour. Mostly when there is no correct result anyway, like with out-of-range values for `floor` et al. But sometimes even in places with meaningful results, e.g. `(realToFrac :: Float -> Double) (0/0)` produces `-5.104235503814077e38` without optimisations, `NaN` with optimisations. The language report says `realToFrac = fromRational . toRational`, which produces the first. Since `Rational` can't really handle `NaN`s and infinities, there's no good way to treat them in that conversion and they're clobbered. The primop preserves them.

Comment: True, @C.A.McCann, but in this case, the `NaN`s add no fun beyond what you already get with infinities.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to your BINARY_CLASS instance for `MPI`.  If I change

```
main = do
  print packet
  print (decode (encode packet) :: SignatureSubpacket)
  print $ decode (encode packet) == packet
```

I see the output (compiled with -O2)

```
EmbeddedSignaturePacket (SignaturePacket {version = 2, signature_type = 168, key_algorithm = ECDSA, hash_algorithm = SHA256, hashed_subpackets = [], unhashed_subpackets = [SignatureCreationTimePacket 1013401916,IssuerPacket "36FE856F4219F1C7"], hash_head = 48065, signature = [MPI 4,MPI 11,MPI 60,MPI 69,MPI 37,MPI 33,MPI 18,MPI 72,MPI 41,MPI 36,MPI 43,MPI 41,MPI 53,MPI 9,MPI 53,MPI 35,MPI 3,MPI 40,MPI 14,MPI 79,MPI 1,MPI 4,MPI 51,MPI 23,MPI 62,MPI 62,MPI 62,MPI 7,MPI 68,MPI 51,MPI 13,MPI 49,MPI 8,MPI 64,MPI 32,MPI 50,MPI 59,MPI 17,MPI 43,MPI 12,MPI 67,MPI 5,MPI 67,MPI 5,MPI 25,MPI 63,MPI 0,MPI 53,MPI 2,MPI 36,MPI 83,MPI 39,MPI 54,MPI 65,MPI 54,MPI 35,MPI 62,MPI 63,MPI 26,MPI 4,MPI 82,MPI 57,MPI 85,MPI 71,MPI 43,MPI 77], trailer = Chunk "\168" (Chunk "<gI<" Empty)})
EmbeddedSignaturePacket (SignaturePacket {version = 2, signature_type = 168, key_algorithm = ECDSA, hash_algorithm = SHA256, hashed_subpackets = [], unhashed_subpackets = [SignatureCreationTimePacket 1013401916,IssuerPacket "36FE856F4219F1C7"], hash_head = 48065, signature = [MPI 4,MPI 11,MPI 60,MPI 69,MPI 37,MPI 33,MPI 18,MPI 72,MPI 41,MPI 36,MPI 43,MPI 41,MPI 53,MPI 9,MPI 53,MPI 35,MPI 3,MPI 40,MPI 14,MPI 79,MPI 1,MPI 4,MPI 51,MPI 23,MPI 62,MPI 62,MPI 62,MPI 7,MPI 68,MPI 51,MPI 13,MPI 49,MPI 8,MPI 64,MPI 32,MPI 50,MPI 59,MPI 17,MPI 43,MPI 12,MPI 67,MPI 5,MPI 67,MPI 5,MPI 25,MPI 63,MPI 0,MPI 0,MPI 339782829898145924110968965855122255180100961470274369007196973863828909184332476115285611703086303618816635857833592912611149], trailer = Chunk "\168" (Chunk "<gI<" Empty)})
```

Changing your MPI instance to this more straightforward implementation:

```
newtype MPI = MPI Integer deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord)
instance BINARY_CLASS MPI where
  put (MPI i) = do
    put (fromIntegral $ B.length bytes :: Word16)
    putSomeByteString bytes
    where
    bytes = if B.null bytes' then B.singleton 0 else bytes'
    bytes' = B.pack . map (read . (:[])) $ show i
  get = do
    length <- fmap fromIntegral (get :: Get Word16)
    bytes <- getSomeByteString length
    return (MPI $ read $ concatMap show $ B.unpack bytes)
```

fixes the problem.

There are a few things that could be the problem source.  It's possible that your code is correct (I haven't checked this one way or the other), in which case GHC is performing some invalid transformation leading to an overflow/underflow somewhere.  It's also possible that your code is doing something incorrect that is only exposed by certain optimizations.